# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass - but only when rendering on homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Person` and I want to list all 'people' on the home page of my website.

I created a partial _index.html.erb for this, so I could use this list everywhere on my website. On index.html.erb, I render this partial.

Now both http://localhost:3000/people/ and http://localhost:3000/people/index run fine. However, I also wanted to use the index partial on my home page. There, it gives the following error:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Some parts of my code:

**people/_index.html.erb**

```
<h2>The following people exist:</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <% @people.each do |p| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= p.name %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**people/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'people/index' %>
```

pages/index.html.erb (This is my home page)

```
<h1>Homepage</h1>

<%= render 'people/new' %>
<%= render 'people/index' %>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
  get 'pages/index'
  get 'people/index'
  resources :people
end
```

Part of people_controller.rb:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def show
    @person = Person.find(person_params)
  end

...
```

Somehow, rendering people/new (also a partial) works perfectly fine if I comment out `<%= render 'people/index' %>`.

Searching for this error leads mainly to the solution "you didn't properly define @people in the controller". However, why does it then work fine on the /people/index page but not when rendering it on the homepage? Is it a routing issue?

I hope that my question is clear and that I posted enough code snippets, thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PagesController`, which is called when you hit the `pages/index` route when rendering the homepage, doesn't have `@people` defined, so `@people` ends up being `nil`, and the error occurs.

You need to add `@people = People.all` somewhere in your `PagesController`, since `PeopleController` doesn't actually get called when you access the homepage.

If you check your `development.log` you will see `PeopleController` does not get called when you access the homepage and the `people/_index` partial renders.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` means that you are calling each on something you *think* is there, but isn't. In this case your calling `@people.each`, but @people is actually nil. So you see that error. In your controller set `@people = People.all` in the action/method that is actually fueling that page. So if you are on the show page, it would go in the show method. On the edit page, makes sure that code is in the edit method.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for helping! From the homepage I call the partial _index, so that would mean the action 'fueling' the page would be the action 'index' within PeopleController right? And there I did indeed set @people to Person.all.... 

Is it because I call a partial?

Comment: @user133910 " the action 'fueling' the page would be the action 'index' within PeopleController right" - aren't you opening home page? In which case, PeopleController has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Indeed, that's where I made my mistake! I added `@people` to my PagesController and the problem was solved. Thanks!